Different handling of null and absent value in json using jackson scala deserialization
I am deserializing json into Scala case classes using jackson and struggle with handling of optional attributes and default values, e.g.
case class MyClass(val1: Option[String] = Some("default"))

I would like to have the following behavior:
If the json...

contains the attribute A and the value is...

V, we will initialize the case class attribute A with Some(V)
null, we will initialize the case class attribute A with None (here is the problem)


does not contain the attribute we will initialize the case class attribute A with the provided default value

So I need a differentiation between the attribute is null and the attribute does not exist in the file.
I am using jackson 2.15.3 to deserialize a json to a Scala case class.
The issue is that the case attribute is null does not work as expected. It is not initialized with None but with the provided default value (Some("default")).
Some background: The generated json are actually coming from a dhall based workflow and there I have the ability to define optional attributes. This needs to be transfered over to json (using dhall-to-json --preserve-null). The Python binding consuming the json (using pydantic) works as expected. So I would like to have jackson do it same way.
The following scalatest demonstrates the problem:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpec

// this is the case class with an optional value that defaults to some value
case class MyClass(val1: Option[String] = Some("default"))

class DeserializeNullSimpleTest extends AnyWordSpec {
  def createMapper(): JsonMapper =
    JsonMapper
      .builder()
      .addModule(DefaultScalaModule)
      .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
      .build()

  val defaultMapper = createMapper()

  "val1 is defined as fubar and should result in fubar" in {
    val myClass = defaultMapper.readValue(
      """{"val1": "fubar"}""",
      classOf[MyClass]
    )
    assert(myClass.val1.contains("fubar"))
  }

  "val1 is defined as null and should result in None" in {
    val myClass = defaultMapper.readValue(
      """{"val1": null}""",
      classOf[MyClass]
    )
    // THIS TEST FAILS WITH 'Some("default") was not empty'
    assert(myClass.val1.isEmpty)
  }

  "val1 is missing in json and should result in default" in {
    val myClass =
      defaultMapper.readValue("""{}""", classOf[MyClass])
    assert(myClass.val1.contains("default"))
  }
}

SBT Dependencies are
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core"     % "jackson-databind"        % "2.15.3",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype" % "jackson-datatype-jsr310" % "2.15.3",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module"  %% "jackson-module-scala"    % "2.15.3",
  "org.scalactic"                 %% "scalactic"               % "3.2.18",
  "org.scalatest"                 %% "scalatest"               % "3.2.18" % "test"
)

The second test fails (json is {"val1": null}, because the case class gets initialized with default value Some("default") and not None.
How can I instruct jackson to handle all these three cases?
Thanks a lot

Partially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44994335/jackson-ignores-custom-field-deserializer-when-value-is-null

checked it and it seems to be different. If I omit the default value from the case class and my json contains a null, the case class argument will be initialized with None. So the general handling of null is fine. The issue is that the provided default is used even if null is provided in the json
